# I can't run my JAR file on Windows Vista

Tags: java, jar, batch-file, cmd

I have recently made a .JAR file called Electronics.jar

(located in C:\Java\eclipse\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin>Electronics.jar)

and it won't run. I have tried loads of different methods of running it. I have used the command

```
C:\Java\eclipse\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin>javaw -jar Electronics.jar
```

in the command prompt, I have tried the same command run from a batch file, and I have tried double clicking on the icon in windows explorer. The latter method made a popup box appear, asking which program I wanted to use to open the file. I found the javaw.exe file, selected it, and tried to run it with that, but nothing happened. Can anyone help?

Comment: a runnable jar file need specify Main-Class in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file, maybe you missed this

Comment: Have you tried assoc and ftype yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can find it on windows explorer what you can do it's go to the location of the file (while in windows explorer) `shift + rightClick` in a blank space, then choose `open command prompt here` and try executing `java Electronics.jar`

Comment: Tried that, got an error: Cannot find or load main class Electronics.jar

Comment: You do have a main class in your code right ? `void main(String[] args){ // all of your code }`

Comment: Of course; the program runs fine if I run the .class file from the command prompt or in Eclipse. The only time it doesn't run is in the JAR file. By the way, it's a JFrame, so the main() goes at the bottom, and only has one line: Electronics g = new Electronics();

Comment: I write the code in Eclipse (for error checking) then copy and paste it into notepad, save the file, then compile and save it in a JAR file

Comment: I would recommend you to just use full Eclipse for building and everything, any reason why you do it like this ?

Comment: I just wanted to run the program independently of eclipse, so I could make a permanent application in Windows Explorer, so I wouldn't have to open eclipse just to use the program

Comment: You can just 'build' the project and will get the same "permanent application" when you build it from eclipse you will get rhe same jar and won't need to open eclipse to run it

Comment: How do I do that? Is it written and saved to eclipse norally, or do I have to do something?

Comment: You must have everything into an eclipse project, then on the menu of eclipse while selecting your project just go to `Project > Build Project` and in the folder where your project is saved you should find a `dist` foler where your .jar should be and you can just use it without eclipse

Comment: #when I go to Project>Build project, the build project selection is grey, and I am unable to click it. What am I doing wrong? (I use eclipse europa)

Comment: Are you sure your project it's selected on the left side panel where all your projects should be ?. Also you can check around Eclipse's Documentation: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-32.htm&cp=1_3_1

Comment: No wait - I've created the JAR file, but it won't run. I followed all the steps in the help link u sent 2 me, the JAR was definitely created, but when I double click the icon in my desktop, nothing happens. (In case it's relevant, I use windows vista and eclipse europa)

Comment: does your program has a GUI (Graphical User Interface) ? or is it everything via command line ?

Comment: It is a JFrame electronics calculator, so it uses JRadioButtons, JLabels and JTextFields.

Comment: Man just send it to me i'll compile it and send it back to you